# rebootなしでシステム全体のLANGやLC_ALLを変更するには？

Tags: linux, debian

debianで `LANG` や `LC_ALL` を設定してないと`apt-get install`しただけで下記のようなperlのエラーがでます。

```
$ sudo apt-get install foo
...
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

現状は下記のshell scriptで対応しているのですがrebootが必要になってしまいます。

```
if ! grep -Fq "LC_ALL" /etc/environment; then
  sed -i 's/.*ja_JP.UTF-8 UTF-8.*/ja_JP.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen
  locale-gen
  cat < /etc/environment
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8
EOF
  source /etc/environment
fi
```

（`en_US.UTF-8` でもかまいません）

reboot無しで上記warningを出さないようにする方法はありますでしょうか。

宜しくお願いします。

http://docs.komagata.org/5227

Comment: chef（私の場合はsunzi）などのツールで設定する時のことを想定しているので、reboot無しでみんなどうやってるのか気になりました。

Comment: shell script は どのように読み込んでますか？ もし **/bin/sh filename** のように実行している場合は **. filename** で読み込んでみてください。あとrebootする前の状態で locale を実行するとどう表示されますか？ 同様に Perlの警告の LANG と LC_ALL はなんと報告されますか？このへんいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

reboot を回避するということで、質問のなかに既に書かれている、`source /etc/environment` をされるのがダメということであれば、環境変数の有効範囲を限定してはどうでしょうか。

コマンド実行単位だと、以下のようになります。

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 apt-get install foo
```

その後、コマンド実行単位ではなく、「必要なサービスが特定のロケールを必要としている」という必要が生まれてたなら :

- サービス起動スクリプト毎に上記のような変更をする
- 専用ユーザを作り、必要なロケールを設定したうえで、サービスはそのユーザが実行する

のどちらかで対処できるはずです。

（複数サービスが起動する環境で、１つのサービスがシステム全体のロケールの変更を求める状態は、あまりよくないので。。。）

Comment: `source /etc/environment`しても`apt-get`時に上記perlエラーが出てしまうんですよね。

Comment: そもそもロケールがないだとぉ・・・

`sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8 ja_JP.EUC-JP EUC-JP ja_JP.UTF-8 UTF-8` の後、 
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` ではどうでしょう。これで、足りないロケールが追加されるはずです。

Comment: chefやsunziのような自動設定スクリプトで使うためのreboot無しですので対話的な設定はできないです。

またlocale-genは上記スクリプト内で行っています。